# Play music after selecting track from media player

Tags: android

I want to select a track from music player and then return the selected track to my app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setData(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

then in OnAcvtivityResult, i'm storing the result in a string.

```
String song=data.getData().toString();
```

then when user presses a button, I want to play the music

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent();  
intent1.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
File file = new File(song);  
intent1.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");  
startActivity(intent1);
```

but this does not work. It shows that cannot play files of this format.
How can I correct this??

Comment: seems the media player does not support the format of the file that you want to play. check this http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: the value of string song i get after selecting a particular track is   content://media/external/audio/media/1

I believe this is not a valid name.
So how can I receive a valid name which can be later played on music player?